# Get media with AVDepthData without an iPhone 7+

Tags: image, depth, ios11, iphone7plus

What's the best way to build apps for the AVDepthData without owning an iPhone 7+?

The depth data can only be captured on the iPhone 7+ that has the dual lenses camera. But I guess any iOS11 device can handle the depth data provided it has access to photos that contain it. I could not find any such media resource from Apple or other parties online. Does anyone has some? Or is there a better way?

I've tried to look into the iPhone 7+ simulator library, but the simulator crashes because it's not supporting Metal that the depth demo apps are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need someone (like me) that has an iPhone 7+ with iOS 11 on it to send you an image.

Visit this link with Safari on iOS 11 and tap `more...` -> `Save Image`

http://hellocamera.co/img/depth-photo.heic

Note: I removed the gps data from this image.

Answer (score 5):

Though a non-trival task, it is possible to generate AVDepthData and add it to your own image.

1. create a depth/disparity dictionary like that documented in `CGImageSource.h` `CGImageSourceCopyAuxiliaryDataInfoAtIndex`- however, following are more details:

Key `kCGImageAuxiliaryDataInfoData` - (`CFDataRef`) - the depth data

Contains just a binary pixel buffer. As in it’s the data you pull out of a pixel buffer by reading the pointer in CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress. You create the CVPixelBuffer with a format of one of the supported types:

- kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat16         = 'hdis',     /* IEEE754-2008 binary16 (half float), describing the normalized shift when comparing two images. Units are 1/meters: ( pixelShift / (pixelFocalLength * baselineInMeters) ) */
- kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat32         = 'fdis',     /* IEEE754-2008 binary32 float, describing the normalized shift when comparing two images. Units are 1/meters: ( pixelShift / (pixelFocalLength * baselineInMeters) ) */
- kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat16             = 'hdep',     /* IEEE754-2008 binary16 (half float), describing the depth (distance to an object) in meters */
- kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32             = 'fdep',     /* IEEE754-2008 binary32 float, describing the depth (distance to an object) in meters */

To turn an arbitrary grayscale image into a fake depth buffer, you’ll need to per-pixel convert whatever your grayscale pixel values are (0=black to 1=white, zNear to zFar, etc) to either meters or 1/meters depending on your target format. And get them into the right floating-point format, depending on where you’re getting them from.

Key `kCGImageAuxiliaryDataInfoDataDescription` - (`CFDictionary`) - the depth data description

Tells you how to interpret that buffer for one we give you, or tells us how to interpret a buffer you give us:

- kCGImagePropertyPixelFormat is one of the CoreVideo/CVPixelBuffer.h depth/disparity formats
- kCGImagePropertyWidth/Height are the pixel dimensions
- kCGImagePropertyBytesPerRow is correctly what it says on the tin

Key `kCGImageAuxiliaryDataInfoMetadata` - (`CGImageMetadataRef`) - metadata

This value is optional.

2. Create AVDepthData with [init(fromDictionaryRepresentation: [AnyHashable : Any])](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdata/2881221-init) passing the dictionary created above.
3. Create an image using ImageI/O:

   ```
   // create the image destination (not shown)

   // add an image to the destination
   CGImageDestinationAddImage(cgImageDestination, renderedCGImage, attachments)  

   // Use AVDepthData to get auxiliary data dictionary
   ```

   var auxDataType :NSString?

   let auxData = depthData.dictionaryRepresentation(forAuxiliaryDataType: &auxDataType)

   ```
   // Add auxiliary data to image destination  
   CGImageDestinationAddAuxiliaryDataInfo(cgImageDestination, auxDataType!, auxData! as CFDictionary)  

   if CGImageDestinationFinalize(cgImageDestination) {  
       return data as Data  
   }
   ```

Comment: 2) Create AVDepthData ... How it do in right way? Metadata is not saved https://stackoverflow.com/q/55043630/820795

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can handle depth data of photos on any iOS device. All you need is samples of photos taken by iPhone 7+. [Here](http://bgr.com/2016/09/21/iphone-7-plus-camera-samples-photos-test/) are a few of them.

Comment: The article is from 2016 ie iOS10, so I doubt the depth data is already present in the exported photos. But I'll confirm that

Comment: Did you find anything, @Guig?